# Problem with java main class after updating spring boot from 2.1.4 to 2.1.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

After updating `spring-boot-starter-parent` from 2.1.4 to 2.1.5, I got the exception `no main manifest attribute, in app.jar` when running in docker.

I have changed nothing else in the project.

I have tried to add the main class in the pom like:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <start-class>mypackage.MyApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

I does not help at all.

I am using maven 3.6.1 and java 11.

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: how are you creating your jar?

Comment: Using the maven-jar-plugin with the standard spring boot configuration. I do not have it in my pom. (It is in the spring boot pom)

Comment: You should check if there is a second jar file in `target` directory which is larger than the other file this one should be started...

Comment: Are you sure this problem will disappear after you change back to 2.1.4?

Answer (score 2):

Try in your pom.xml add mainClass,

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>mypackage.MyApplication</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem still remains with that configuration.